# How to give space between theorem number and theorem?

Tags: number, theoremname

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{extsizes}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\usepackage[
    top=1.75cm, % Top margin
    bottom=3.5cm, % Bottom margin
    left=3.25cm, % Left margin
    right=3.25cm, % Right margin
        footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,
hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks=true,% Set to false to disable coloring links
citecolor=magenta,% The color of citations
linkcolor=black,% The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
urlcolor=mdtRed,% The color of hyperlinks (URLs)
pdfstartview={FitV},
unicode,
breaklinks=true,
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}

   \newtheoremstyle{custom}% name
    {12pt}% Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {\parshape 3 0pt \textwidth \parindent \dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent 0pt \textwidth}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}% Space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}{\mdseries\thmnote{ [#3]}}}% Theorem head spec(can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{custom}
\swapnumbers
 \newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}[section]
    \newenvironment{thm}
      {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\thmx}
      {\popQED\endthmx}
\newtheorem*{demostracion}{Demostración}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposición}[section]
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}

\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large}{\textbf{\chaptername $~$ \thechapter.} }{0pt}{\Large}

\newcommand{\Mysquare}{\raisebox{.25\height}{\tiny$\square$}}
%\newcommand{\Mysquare}{\square}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Set the page style to "fancy"...
\pagestyle{fancy}
%... then configure it.
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{The performance of new graduates}}
%\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{OPOSICIONES}
\fancyfoot[r]{Azahara Carpintero}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{left}
\fancyfoot[r]{right}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{transparent}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\chapter{Dumy Chapter}
\section{Dumy Section}
\begin{theo}[\bfseries Fundamental de la programación lineal]
 \textit{ Si un PPL tiene soluciones óptimas. alguna de ellas se alcanza en uno de los vértices del conjunto convexo $S$ de soluciones factible. Si, además, se alcanza solución óptima en más de un vértice de $S$, también son soluciones óptimas las combinaciones lineales convexas de dichos vértices. } 
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to add space between theorem number and theorem equal to space between section number and title of section.]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but you shouldn't use `\swapnumbers` if you define and use a custom theorem style where you specify the last argument to `\newtheoremstyle`.

Here's an edited version of your preamble, that's rather messy: first load packages, so you avoid duplications and incompatibilities. Note that `hyperref` has to be last (with a few exceptions not present among your packages).

I added comments about packages. In particular, *don't* inhibit hyphenation, but use `babel` in order to get correct hyphenation for Spanish.

I also changed the `\newtheoremstyle` declaration, because `\parshape` has no meaning where you had it. Note that with this new code, you don't need to specify fonts neither for the theorem label nor for the body.

A note: you define `thm` in terms of `thmx`, but don't define the latter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{fix-cm}% not extsizes

\usepackage[
  a4paper, % did you forget?
  top=1.75cm, % Top margin
  bottom=3.5cm, % Bottom margin
  left=3.25cm, % Left margin
  right=3.25cm, % Right margin
  footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
  headheight=14.5pt, % as requested by fancyhdr
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % don't! really, I mean it.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol} % are you sure?
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

%\usepackage{float} % don't use [H]
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{transparent}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,eso-pic}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last
\hypersetup{
  pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=0,
  hypertexnames=false,
  colorlinks=true,% Set to false to disable coloring links
  citecolor=magenta,% The color of citations
  linkcolor=black,% The color of references to document elements (sections, figures, etc)
  urlcolor=mdtRed,% The color of hyperlinks (URLs)
  pdfstartview={FitV},
  unicode,
  breaklinks=true,
}

\newtheoremstyle{custom}% name
  {12pt}% Space above
  {3pt}% Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}% Space after theorem head
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ [#3]}}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{custom}

\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}[section]
\newenvironment{thm}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\thmx}
  {\popQED\endthmx}
\newtheorem*{demostracion}{Demostración}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposición}[section]

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {\chaptername\ \thechapter. }
  {0pt}
  {}


%\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
%\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
%\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}}

% Set the page style to "fancy"...
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%... then configure it.
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{The performance of new graduates}}
%\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{OPOSICIONES}
\fancyfoot[r]{Azahara Carpintero}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[l]{left}%
  \fancyfoot[r]{right}%
}

% personal commands
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\newcommand{\Mysquare}{\raisebox{.25\height}{\tiny$\square$}}
%\newcommand{\Mysquare}{\square}


\begin{document}
%\sloppy % why?

\chapter{Dumy Chapter}

\section{Dumy Section}

\begin{theo}[Fundamental de la programación lineal]
Si un PPL tiene soluciones óptimas. alguna de ellas se alcanza en uno 
de los vértices del conjunto convexo $S$ de soluciones factible. Si, 
además, se alcanza solución óptima en más de un vértice de $S$, también 
son soluciones óptimas las combinaciones lineales convexas de dichos vértices.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see the space between section number and section title is more than the space between theorem number and "Theorem". And I want to give the space between theorem number and "Theorem" as in the Section number and section title .

Comment: @SamiaRani `\thmnumber{\quad #2}`

Comment: But it is not working in my case.

Comment: @SamiaRani OK, that's because the `\quad` in the section title is for `\Large`. Use `\thmnumber{{\Large\quad}#2}`. Then look at the result and return to the standard space.

Comment: He means the vertical space, doesn't he?

Comment: @user206750 I don't think so.